# Leibniz Alternating Series Test

Tags: calculus

Can someone help me find a Leibniz Series (alternating sum) that converges to $5$ ?

Does such a series even exist?

Thanks in advance!!!

I've tried looking at a series of the form $ \sum _ 1 ^\infty (-1)^{n} q^n $ which is a geometric series ... But I get $q>1 $ , which is impossible... Does someone have an idea?

Comment: Do you know the sum of some alternating series?

Comment: Try $1+q=1/5$...

Comment: $ then I get $q < 0 ...  $ which gives me negative elements...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cook up an alternating series that hits any sum $S$ you like as follows.

1. Pick a geometric series (with first term of 1) with geometric ratio $r$, with $-1<r<0$. Its sum will be ${1\over 1-r}$.
2. This is also an alternating series since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^{n}|r|^n$.
3. If you want the final sum to be $S$, then you just need to multiply the original geometric series by a constant $k$ so that $k\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=S$, but this implies $k=S(1+|r|)$.
4. Thus, you use $$S(1+|r|)\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=S(1+|r|)\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^{n}|r|^n, \quad -1<r<0.$$ It will be alternating and have sum $S$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{16}-\frac{1}{32}+\cdots=\frac{2}{3}$.

Answer (score 2):

Take any Leibniz sequence $x_n$, the series of which converges not to zero, say to $c$, and then consider
the sequence $(\frac5c\cdot x_n)_n$.